# Usng Sidr to create multiple level navigation

Tags: responsive-design, navigation, sidr

I'm using [Sidr](http://www.berriart.com/sidr) to create a multilevel (nested) menu. I'm aiming to achieve a responsive menu like: http://www.currys.co.uk

I've got the 2nd level navigation working well, but haven't been able to get any further levels working.

HTML:

```
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="left-menu"><a href="/link1">Level 1 Example</a>
                <ul class="subnav-l2">
                    <li class="close"><a href="#" onclick="$.sidr('close', 'sidr-left');return false;">Close Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level 2 Example</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level 2 Example</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level 2 Example</a></li>

                    <li class="left-menu-l3"><a href="#">Level 3 Example</a>
                        <ul class="subnav-l3">
                            <li><a href="#">Link Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link Example 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link Example 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link Example 4</a></li>
                        </ul>   
                    </li>   
                    <li><a href="#">Official Report</a></li>

                </ul>               
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Level 1 Example</a>

        </ul>
    </nav>
```

JS:

```
$('.left-menu').sidr({
  name: 'sidr-left',
  side: 'left', // By default
  source: '.subnav-l2'
});

$('.left-menu-l3').sidr({
  name: 'sidr-left2',
  side: 'left', // By default
  source: '.subnav-l3'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be in your footer. Hope this helps.

```
<script src="http://yoursite.domain.../jquery.sidr.min.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery('#responsive-menu-button').sidr({
name: 'sidr-main',
source: '.menu-main-nav-container'
});

jQuery( window ).load(function() {
if(jQuery("#sidr-main").length !== 0) {        
    jQuery(".sidr-class-sub-menu").hide();      
    jQuery( "li.sidr-class-menu-item ul.sidr-class-sub-menu" ).each(function() {
    jQuery( this ).after("<div class='lnk-plus'>+</div>");
    });

    jQuery( ".lnk-plus" ).toggle(function() {
        var id1= jQuery( this ).parent().attr("id");
        jQuery("#" + id1 + " ul.sidr-class-sub-menu").show();
        jQuery("#" + id1 + " .sidr-class-menu-item-has-children ul").hide();   
        jQuery( this ).html("-");
        }, function() {
        var id1= jQuery( this ).parent().attr("id");
        jQuery("#" + id1 + " ul.sidr-class-sub-menu").hide();
        jQuery( this ).html("+");
        });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Please notice where `jQuery(".sidr-class-sub-menu").hide();` is situated.

For iPad and iPhone, you have to use a separate snippet which is slightly different, it uses `.bind` and touchstart event to make it work.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(ipad|iphone)/);
        if (agentID) {      
            jQuery('#responsive-menu-button').sidr({
                name: 'sidr-main',
                source: '.menu-main-nav-container'
            });

            if(jQuery("#sidr-main").length !== 0) {
                jQuery(window).bind('touchstart click', function(){ 
                        //return false
                });

                jQuery( ".lnk-plus" ).toggle(function() {
                var id1= jQuery( this ).parent().attr("id");
                jQuery("#" + id1 + " ul.sidr-class-sub-menu").show("slow");
                jQuery("#" + id1 + " .sidr-class-menu-item-has-children ul").hide("slow");   
                jQuery( this ).html("-");
                }, function() {
                var id1= jQuery( this ).parent().attr("id");
                jQuery("#" + id1 + " ul.sidr-class-sub-menu").hide("slow");
                jQuery( this ).html("+");
                }); 

            }                   
        }
});
</script>
```